# reverse implementation Seq

Tags: scala

In the class `SeqLike.scala` there is a function called `reverse` which reverses a sequence. For example it makes `List(1,2,3,4)` to `List(4,3,2,1)

In the source, the description is:

```
def reverse: Repr = {
var xs: List[A] = List() //Line 1
for (x <- this)
  xs = x :: xs
val b = newBuilder ////Line 4
b.sizeHint(this)
for (x <- xs)
  b += x
b.result
}
```

What I dont understand, is: Line (1-3) does the job. But why does it make a new builder and then add elements to it to return. Just Line[1-3] will suffice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lines 1-3 generate a `List`.  But `reverse` is not supposed to return any old `Seq` but the same type of `Seq` as it got.  So if it's actually a list it doesn't need the extra builder step; otherwise it does.  (And if you look in the implementation of `List`, it doesn't do the extra work.)

```
override def reverse: List[A] = {
  var result: List[A] = Nil
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    result = these.head :: result
    these = these.tail
  }
  result
}
```